# Avoid Switch statement redundancy when multiple Cases do the same thing?

Tags: java, syntax, switch-statement

I have multiple cases in a switch that do the same thing, like so: (this is written in Java)

```
 case 1:
     aMethod();
     break;
 case 2:
     aMethod();
     break;
 case 3:
     aMethod();
     break;
 case 4:
     anotherMethod();
     break;
```

Is there any way I can combine cases 1, 2 and 3 into one case, since they all call the same method?

Answer (score 25):

```
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
    aMethod();
    break;
case 4:
    anotherMethod();
    break;
```

This works because when it happens to be case 1 (for instance), it falls through to case 2 (no `break` statement), which then falls through to case 3.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, you can allow `case` clause sections for 1 & 2 to 'fall through' to clause 3 and then `break` out of the `switch` statement after that:

```
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
     aMethod();
     break;
case 4:
     anotherMethod();
     break;
```

Comment: what if 3 and 4 has some common part, but 4 does some additional stuff

Comment: In that case you can let 3 "fall through" to 4. The question here indicates that 3 and 4 have no shared functionality

Comment: Well, no, you can't let 3 fall through to 4. In that case, anything done for case 4 would always get done for case 3 as well and it would be 3 that would be doing the extra stuff (before falling through). Using a `switch`, you can only do the additional stuff _before_ the common stuff. If you want other logic, you need to use other control structures (or `if` statements nested inside switch cases, which I find ugly).

Answer (score 4):

Below is the best you can do

```
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
     aMethod();
     break;
 case 4:
     anotherMethod();
     break;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's called the "fall through" pattern:

```
case 1:  // fall through
case 2:  // fall through
case 3: 
   aMethod(); 
   break; 
case 4: 
   anotherMethod(); 
   break;
```